# How to send a shutdown signal in Ubuntu when nvidia-smi returns error?

Tags: shutdown, monitoring, ubuntu-16.04, systemd, nvidia-settings

How to write a script or edit systemd settings to shutdown Ubuntu when it the GPU is down. The This script has to be constantly pinging the availability of the GPU and shutdown the system automatically to prevent damage.